# How to make asynchronous database operations with Twisted?

Tags: postgresql, asynchronous, twisted

I am a newbie in working with Twisted. I have many clients sending data permanently to the serve, the server must insert those data in the database(Postgresql).

My problem is that my server does not behave asynchronously:

for example: in t=0, a client sends data that take 30 seconds to be inserted in the database, in t=10: another client sends data to the server: this second client have to wait 20 seconds (30-10) until the server inserts data of the first client.

I want that data should be inserted asynchronously without waiting. A little help will be very appreciated. Here is my code:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol
from twisted.python import log
import sys,psycopg2

class Server(protocol.Protocol):

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        self.client_host = self.transport.getPeer().host
        self.client_port = self.transport.getPeer().port
        cursor=self.factory.connection.cursor()
        self.factory.insert_data(data,self.client_host,cursor)

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        log.msg('Connection lost from %s:%s.\n' % (self.client_host,str(self.client_port)))            

class My_Factory(protocol.ServerFactory):

    protocol = Server

    def __init__(self):
            params="host='127.0.0.1' port='5432' dbname='my_db' user='user' password='my_pwd'"
            try: 
                self.connection= psycopg2.connect(params)
                self.connection.autocommit = True
            except Exception as e:
                log.msg("Cannot connect to database!! Please verify connection params. Reason: %s"%str(e))
                sys.exit(0)


    def insert_data(self,data,adress,cursor):
        try:
            query = """INSERT INTO my_table(
                            data,client_adress, date)
                            VALUES (%s, %s, now());
                    """%(data,adress)
            cursor.execute(query)
        except Exception as e:
            log.msg("Error: "+str(e))




def main(argv):
    log.startLogging(sys.stdout)() 
    my_factory=My_Factory()
    reactor.listenTCP(8000,my_factory)
    reactor.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

Try [twisted.enterprise.adbapi](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.enterprise.adbapi.html) or [twext.enterprise.adbapi2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/twextpy).

Comment: Thank you Sir Jean-Paul,
I figured out that is my problem is that I am using a SINGLE process for all clients, so it is normal that the server serves them one by one(synchronously).

Comment: That's... sort of true.  Most Twisted-based applications use only a single process (and a single thread), though.  You can still benefit from talking to the database asynchronously.  The database might run multiple processes, for example.  If two clients show up and cause you to run two SELECT statements the database might be able to process them concurrently.  If you use an asynchronous API to talk to the database then you have a chance of this happening.  If you use a synchronous API then your application won't even try to ask the database to do them both at the same time.

Comment: I have a question Sir Jean-Paul:
Why Twisted does not create a thread for each new client and then defers the job to the thread (the max number of clients in my case is 400) ?

Comment: Because Twisted is not a library for multithreaded application development.  Twisted is a library for cooperative multitasking and event-driven application development.  If you want a ton of threads screwing things up left and right then you might want a different library.